# hexo with tailwind and postcss

Tags: postcss, hexo, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use tailwind with hexo. It looks from https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/#using-tailwind-with-postcss that I need wire up postcss so I have based myself on https://github.com/chuangker/hexo-renderer-postcss

I tried changing the renderer to read

```
"use strict";

var postcss = require("postcss");
var postcssrc = require("postcss-load-config");
var atImport = require("postcss-import");

console.log("postcss2 registering");

module.exports = function(data) {
    console.log("postcssrc", data);
    return postcssrc()
        .then(({ plugins, options }) => {
            console.log("tailwind", plugins, options);
            return postcss(plugins)
                .use(atImport())
                .process(data.text, options);
        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log("tailwind 2", result);
            return result.css;
        });
};
```

This is converting `@import "tailwindcss/base";` in my css files to `@tailwind base` correctly, but I cant seem to get tailwind applied to that with:

```
module.exports = {
    from: undefined,
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: require("tailwindcss")
    }
};
```

or

```
module.exports = {
    from: undefined,
    plugins: [require("tailwindcss")]
};
```

So that's where I need help

Answer (score 0):

> Can check out the plugin I made for this [hexo-renderer-tailwindcss](https://github.com/TriDiamond/hexo-renderer-tailwindcss)

I got it working with the following:

## renderer.js

```js
'use strict'

var postcss = require('postcss')
var postcssrc = require('postcss-load-config')

module.exports = function (data) {
  return postcssrc().then(({
      plugins,
      options
    }) => postcss(plugins).process(data.text, options))
    .then((result) => result.css)
}
```

## hexo-render-postcss.js

```js
'use strict'

var renderer = require('../libs/postcss/renderer')

hexo.extend.renderer.register('css', 'css', renderer)
```

## hexo root `.postcssrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  from: undefined,
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    'tailwindcss': {},
    'autoprefixer': {},
  }
}
```